# How to set value in date UDF using SAP B1 JCO?

Tags: sapb1, jco, sapjco3

I am able to set String value to UDF using JCO like below.

```
invoice.getLines().getUserFields().getFields().item(java.lang.Object aIndex).setValue(java.lang.Object aValue)
```

But it is not working for date type UDF like (Purchase date, Payment Date).

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this format yyyyMMdd.

Comment: Hi, I got the solution by passing date in "yyyy-MM-dd" format.